# How to watch localeStorage changes in Pinia state?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I have an item called `nuxt-color-mode` saved in localeStorage. It has either `dark` or `light` value. And I would like to watch the value of this item from any component. So I put the Setup & Option Stores that I tried for now! By the way I'm using Nuxt 3!

'~/stores/colorTheme.ts/'

```ts
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

// Option Stores
export const useColorThemeStore = defineStore('colorThemeStore', {
    state: async () => {
        return { mode: await localStorage.getItem('nuxt-color-mode')};
    },
    getters: {},
    actions: {}
   
});

//Setup Stores
export const useColorThemeStore = defineStore('colorThemeStore', async () => {

    const colorMode = await localStorage.getItem('nuxt-color-mode');
    const mode = ref(colorMode);
    
    return { mode }
   
});
```

'~/component/Portfolio.vue'

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
   import { useColorThemeStore } from '~/stores/colorTheme';

   const mode  = useColorThemeStore(); // Got undedfined!

   watch(mode, () => {
      console.log('Mode = ', mode) // Doesn't watch or print anything!
   })   
</script>
```

Comment: You  can listen to storage events, but the answer is that you likely shouldn't, unless you need to sync this in multiple tabs. Instead consider the store the single source of truth. There's Pinia persistence plugin that does this

Comment: I'm not sur that storage events would be the best option for my case. But i'm going to try this Pinia persistence plugin :)